# resolved | GitHub desn't load images

Tags: image, github

I'm making my portfolio and so far I've used 2 images. In the live preview it was all fine, but once pushed on github, the images don't load. In fact, it gives an error in the console saying that it could not get the images in the path.

Here's the link to my repository: https://github.com/mark1yan0/Portfolio-MarkiyanKmit
I've inserted images on lines 61, 77, 91, 116 of the `index.html` file.

I tried to spot a path mistake but I failed, may you could help me.

Here's also the site on github pages: https://mark1yan0.github.io/Portfolio-MarkiyanKmit/

[problem solved]
Apparently the problem was that i named my local file repository differently than the remote one. Once changed that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

推荐你把
/media/project-photo.jpg
修改为
https://mark1yan0.github.io/Portfolio-MarkiyanKmit/media/project-photo.jpg
or
./media/project-photo.jpg

More details can be found

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#image_loading_errors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/URL